# XTickLabel not display the full range

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to display the full range of x-axis labels which contain 16 elements. For some reason, only 8 show up. Please see example below:

```
figure
density =  (.02:.025:.4);
test=rand(1,16);
plot(test)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',density);
```

As you can see, the x label only display from .02 to .22. It should cover from **.02 to .4.** I tried to play with `XLim` but that didn't help either. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you should plot `test` against `density` - `plot(density,test)`, the way it is now is like `plot(1:length(test),test)`.

second, `'XTickLabel'` sets the xtick **labels** = the ticks **names**, what you want is to set `'XTick'` which sets the ticks **values**:

```
figure
density =  (.02:.025:.4);
tt = rand(1,16);
plot(density,tt)
set(gca,'XTick',density);
```

[image]